# WhatsApp Could-Api Form Template Error code 131008

Tags: whatsapp

I have create a simple 4 screen form template. When I try to send the template it gives me below error

```
{
"error":{
"message":"(#131008) Required parameter is missing",
"type":"OAuthException","code":131008,
"error_data":{
"messaging_product":"whatsapp",
"details":"Please specify a flow button component within template['components']"
},
"fbtrace_id":"Arv-fpF2kmkq2kVcdNwH7_I"
}
}
```

below is my code to send template

```
'{
  "messaging_product": "whatsapp",
  "to": "971551941834",
  "type": "template",
  "template": {
    "name": "searchform",
    "language": {
      "code": "en_US"
    },
  }
}';
```

I am not accepting any parmeters in the template design. What flow button component I should specify.
Thank you for the help.

I tried to search on WhatsApp Community help but no use

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, then I read what the doc. says at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/flows/gettingstarted/sendingaflow

You must add the follow data in the POST json (inside the template object):

```
"components": [
  {
    "type": "button",
    "sub_type": "flow",
    "index": "0",
    "parameters": [
      {
        "type": "action",
        "action": {
          "flow_token": "FLOW_TOKEN",   //**optional**, default is "unused"
          "flow_action_data": {
             ...
          }   // **optional**, json object with the data payload for the first screen
        }
      }
    ]
  }
]
```